# concat array values, if contains duplicates - php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is my array. And i need to concat array values if duplicate exists.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [id] => 3
            [location_id] => 2            
            [location_name] => 1st Floor 
            [type] => 1           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 6
            [location_id] => 2           
            [location_name] => 1st Floor 
            [type] => 1           
        )

    [2] => Array
        (           
            [id] => 7
            [location_id] => 1            
            [location_name] => Ground Floor 
            [type] => 1        
        )

)
```

And below is my code, which doesn't concat on unique values.

```
$conct= array();
foreach ($myArray as $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {               
        if ( ! isset($merged[$key]))
        {
            $conct[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $conct[$key] .= ",".$value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving me.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [id] => 3,6,7
            [location_id] => 2,2,1            
            [location_name] => 1st Floor,1st Floor,Ground Floor
            [type] => 1,1,1       
        )


)
```

And i need to concat the values based on **unique** `location_id` and `location_name`. 
My result array should be.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [id] => 3,6
            [location_id] => 2,2            
            [location_name] => 1st Floor,1st Floor 
            [type] => 1,1           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 7
            [location_id] => 1           
            [location_name] => Ground Floor 
            [type] => 1           
        )


)
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?php

$new_values = array();
$values = array(
    array('id'=> 1, 'location_id' => 2, 'location_name' => '1st Floor','type'=>1),
    array('id'=> 6, 'location_id' => 2, 'location_name' => '1st Floor','type'=>1),
   array('id'=> 7, 'location_id' => 1, 'location_name' => 'Gound Floor','type'=>1),
);

foreach($values as $value) {
    if(isset($new_values[$value['location_id']])) {
        $temp = $new_values[$value['location_id']];
        $temp['id'] .= ',' . $value['id'];
        $temp['location_id'] .= ',' . $value['location_id'];
         $temp['location_name'] .= ',' . $value['location_name'];
          $temp['type'] .= ',' . $value['type'];
        $new_values[$value['location_id']] = $temp;
    } else {
        $new_values[$value['location_id']] = $value;
    }
}

$new_values = array_values($new_values);
print_r($new_values);
?>
```

Output:`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1,6 [location_id] => 2,2 [location_name] => 1st Floor,1st Floor [type] => 1,1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 [location_id] => 1 [location_name] => Gound Floor [type] => 1 ) )`

Answer (score 2):

```
$input  = array(array('id'=>3,'location_id'=>2,'location_name'=>'1st Floor','type'=>1),
                array('id'=>6,'location_id'=>2,'location_name'=>'1st Floor','type'=>1),
                array('id'=>7,'location_id'=>1,'location_name'=>'Ground Floor','type'=>1)
            );
$conct = array();
foreach($input as $k => $_input) {
    foreach($_input as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($conct[$key])) {
            if(check_duplicate($duplicate,$input[$k])) {
                $conct[$key] .= ",".$value;    
            } else {
                $new[$key]  = $value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $conct[$key] = $value;
            if($key=='location_id'||$key=='location_name') 
                $duplicate[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

}

function check_duplicate($duplicate=array(),$input=array()) {

    foreach($duplicate as $dupe) {
        if($dupe===$input['location_id'] || $dupe === $input['location_name'] )
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }

}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($conct);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($new);
```

Comment: Answer Array
(
    [id] => 3,6
    [location_id] => 2,2
    [location_name] => 1st Floor,1st Floor
    [type] => 1,1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 7
    [location_id] => 1
    [location_name] => Ground Floor
    [type] => 1
)